# ZPL II How to make barcode widths consistent?

Tags: width, barcode, zpl-ii

I'm trying to print barcodes but noticed that they print in different label sizes. I was wondering if it is possible to make all the barcode lengths the same?

Basically, is it possible to make unequal barcode labels the same width
For e.g.:

> 119

> 077223097025

> 7464804100589

My Code:

```
^BY3,3,83^FT141,217^BCN,,N,N
^FD>:746480410058>69^FS
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a Zebra-compatible printer, you should select a 2D barcode format if you want identical widths regardless of the number of characters. 2D formats like QR Code, PDF417, MicroPDF417, Codablock or Datamatrix will have a minimum size for 1 to 20 or so characters.

For most 1D barcodes, ZPL supports fixed print ratios or limited options based on the width of each character. The height of the barcode is what limits the size, but the width is determined by the number of characters.

Another alternative is to draw the barcodes using a library and send the resulting symbol to the printer as an image file.